# Pass params into rails path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass params into my rails path helper but my current attempt is not working. Here is what I'm doing now:

```
<%= link_to "Pause Assignment", pause_account_complete_assignment_index_path(@assignment.current_timekeeper) %>
```

### Controller

```
def pause
  binding.pry
end
```

In the controller I'm looking for the params I passed in. But they are not found. Here is what is returned.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"accounts/complete_assignment", "action"=>"pause"} permitted: false>
```

## routes

```
resources :complete_assignment, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  get 'pause', on: :collection
end
```

It may have something to do with the fact I using on collection?

But, basically how do I pass `@assigment.current_timkeeper` in the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass the extra params in hash syntax

```
<%= link_to "Pause Assignment", pause_account_complete_assignment_index_path(current_timekeeper: @assignment.current_timekeeper) %>
```

This will give you params like

```
<ActionController::Parameters {
  "controller"=>"accounts/complete_assignment", 
  "action"=>"pause",
  "current_timekeeper"=>"value_of_current_timekeeper" 
 } permitted: false>
```

Comment: Will I get those params if the value is nil?

Comment: I don't think so